# Automatically shrinking a matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm wondering about a way to automatically shrink down a matrix. I can think of `\arraycolsep` command for the column width but I am not aware of an equivalent command for the height of the lines? Should the whole matrix environment be redefined to allow this?

Comment: probably you can also use a \resizebox{xlenght}{ylength}{contents}

Comment: but it is going to affect the font size as well, that I do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}` and `\def\arraystretch{0.8}` or use smaller values

AN example for the test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\[
\def\arraystretch{3}
\begin{pmatrix}
foo & bar\\
bar & foo
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is not `\arraystretch` for tabular only? not for matrices of type `pmatrix` and so on?

Comment: so the question is "Why don't you test it?" ... ;-)

Comment: well, I tested it and it did not modify anything. I'll try on miniml example then

Comment: @pluton: see my answer